# thread for exact time python

Tags: python, multithreading, delay

I also need to wait for about 1 s by thread.

I've tried this code to access period of thread, but sometimes its actually 1s and other times it takes much longer. Why does it happen?

```
import threading
import time

i=0
def task():

    global t_period
    t_period1   = time.time() - t_period
    t_period = time.time()
    t=threading.Timer(1,task)
    t.start()

    print( t_period1 )




t_period = time.time()
t=threading.Timer(1,task)
t.start()
```

Comment: Here's an extract from the documentation (which I'm sure you've read): "The interval the timer will wait before executing its action may not be exactly the same as the interval specified by the user."

Comment: *How* much longer does this take? Note that because threads are restricted by the GIL and the OS scheduler, all delays are minimums and threads may only be able to run later than that. This also affects individual instructions, e.g. storing the ``t_period`` and running ``t.start()`` may be several milliseconds off even in the best of cases.